# SurfaceView canvas drawing path with transparency

Tags: android, android-canvas, transparency, surfaceview

I have problems with my drawing application. I need to catch the correct touch screen and draw them to the canvas. Changing the size of the brush is working properly. But when I change the transparency setting, the program does not work correctly. It imposes a new path on top of the previous one, and the transparency is lost. [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/axwqme). Where could I go wrong? I need your help. Thank you.

This is my SurfaceView code:

```
    public class PainterView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private PainterThread painterThread;
    private BrushParameters brushParameters;
    private Bitmap bitmap;


    public PainterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        brushParameters = new BrushParameters();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        getThread().setRunning(true);
        getThread().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int width, int height) {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            getThread().setBitmap(bitmap, true);
        } else {
            getThread().setBitmap(bitmap, false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        getThread().setRunning(false);
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                getThread().join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        painterThread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                painterThread.startDraw(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                painterThread.continueDraw(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                painterThread.finishDraw(x, y);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public BrushParameters getBrushParameters() {
        return brushParameters;
    }

    public void setBrushColor(int color) {
        brushParameters.setColor(color);
        getThread().setBrushParameters(brushParameters);
    }

    public void setBrushSize(int size) {
        brushParameters.setSize(size);
        getThread().setBrushParameters(brushParameters);
    }

    public void setBrushAlpha(int alpha) {
        brushParameters.setAlpha(alpha);
        getThread().setBrushParameters(brushParameters);
    }

    public PainterThread getThread() {
        if (painterThread == null) {
            painterThread = new PainterThread(getHolder(), this);
        }
        return painterThread;
    }
}
```

And my Thread class:

```
    public class PainterThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private PainterView painterView;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private float lastX, lastY;

    private static float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    public PainterThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, PainterView painterView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.painterView = painterView;

        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas mCanvas;
        while (running) {
            mCanvas = null;
            try {
                mCanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    if (mCanvas != null) {
                        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                        painterView.postInvalidate();
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (mCanvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, boolean clear) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        if (clear) {
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    public void setBrushParameters(BrushParameters brushParameters) {
        paint.setColor(brushParameters.getColor());
        paint.setAlpha(brushParameters.getAlpha());
        paint.setStrokeWidth(brushParameters.getSize());
    }

    public void startDraw(float x, float y) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    }

    public void continueDraw(float x, float y) {

        float dx = Math.abs(x - lastX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - lastY);

        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            path.quadTo(lastX, lastY, (x + lastX) / 2, (y + lastY) / 2);
            mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
        }
    }

    public void finishDraw(float x, float y) {

        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help. I lost fiew days for find a cause of the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend getting rid of SurfaceView.  You've got some confused-looking code (e.g. `setBitmap()` sets `mCanvas`, but that's getting overwritten in a loop by `run()`), and I think you're just making life harder on yourself.

SurfaceViews have two parts, the Surface and the View.  The Surface is a separate layer that (by default) sits behind the View layer.  The View part of the SurfaceView is normally just a transparent hole that lets you "see through" to the Surface layer behind.

In your case, you've overridden `onDraw()` in the View object, so you're actually drawing in the View.  Over in your other thread you're drawing that same Bitmap onto the Surface.  Even if your Bitmap has transparent pixels, you'll be seeing two identical Bitmaps layered on top of each other.

It looks like you're sharing a Bitmap and possibly a Canvas between two simultaneously-executing threads, which is a recipe for unhappiness.

If you get rid of the SurfaceView, and just use a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), I think everything will make more sense.  The other approach is to get rid of `onDraw()` and the call to `postInvalidate()` and do everything on the Surface, but to take advantage of hardware-accelerated rendering it's better to use the custom View.